# Bean Validation with custom annotation for Integer Type value

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I write a custom Annotation for Integer value validation.

My Dto class is

```
  @PositiveIntegerValue
  private Integer academicSessionYear;
```

It works perfectly for Integer values. But when I send Flot then it automatically converts to Integer and when I send String value from swagger it returns

```
{
  "error": "internal server error"
}
```

For String type value it does not reach the Annotation code. I would like to write an annotation that the request type is Integer and find my annotation coder and I will return custom message except for internal Server error.

Comment: That will never work. How are you going to assign the `String` "Hello World" to an `Integer`? There is no means of translating that into a valid integer and hence it will fail.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get these kinds of things you have mentioned in the comment. Thank you very much. But Can not I able to send a custom message to expect an Internal server error.

Comment: I would Like to handle this exception by my own code Not by the  "internal server error". It is Possble ?

Comment: I would like to handle my custom Annotation. But for type mismatch, it does not reach to my custom Annotation code.

Comment: An annotation is nothing more then meta-data an annotation doesn't do anything. No there isn't a possibility for you to **validate** a conversion that cannot happen. Simpl because there is no way that that string will become a number. So unless you make everything an `Object ` and do everything in code (and hence loose the benefits of types) there isn't another way.

Comment: got it, thank you so much